# Why can't I pump something full of electrons and use it as a hoverboard?

Tags: electrostatics, estimation, coulombs-law, lift

Why can't I pump something full of electrons and use it as a hoverboard? I'm not sure how to calculate how many electrons a material can hold.

Comment: Why do you expect it to work as a hoverboard?

Comment: If you pump something full of electrons you get an electric shock if you touch it. If you keep pumping it farther you get electrocuted if you touch it. If you keep pumping it further still eventually you get a  lightning bolt jumping out at you. That's because electrons repel each other more and more as you bunch them close together and want re-distribute to a more even level.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the possible principle. Let us assume that your "hoverboard" carries some charge (be it negative or positive). This charge will polarize the initially neutral ground in such a way that the hoverboard would be attracted to the ground, rather than repelled from it.

Comment: Not to forget all those sparks

Comment: @annav : this is an important consideration, but it can be addressed (in principle) by an increase of the area of the "hoverboard". But it is not clear how to get repulsion, even in principle.

Comment: If the charge is negative and pulled over a solid state lattice, , would not electron / electron orbitals repulse?

Comment: @annav : they will, but this repulsion will be compensated by attraction to the positively charged nuclei, moreover, as a result, the solid-state body will get polarized and attracted to the negative charge of the "hoverboard".

Comment: Actually readking this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect  it is much more complicated than i assmed

Comment: @annav : I don't think triboelectricity is relevant: triboelectricity involves charge transfer from one body to another. This will not let the "hoverboard" move consistently, as it will be discharging. What I have in mind is "Attraction between a charged object and a neutral object" http://physics.ucsc.edu/~pgraham/spr2009_7b/phys7b_lab2.pdf